# Embed Youtube in Powerpoint 2013

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, youtube, microsoft-office-2013

I have found multiple descriptions on the Internet about how to add Youtube videos in Powerpoint 2013, but in each case I am hung up on a single step. When I go to `Insert`->`Video`->`Online Video` I see the following screen:

[image: Insert online video selection screen]

Everything I have found indicates that Youtube can be an option here, as well as embedding video with the online embed code. However, since I only have the option for Skydrive or Facebook, I'm pretty limited. I've tried adding Youtube as a service through `File`->`Account`->`Connected Services` section, but nothing seems to change.

Technical details:

- Powerpoint 2013, 32-bit (Office Professional Plus)
- Windows 7 Ultimate, 64-bit
- Flash player is installed (both Chrome and IE versions)

Comment: All the guides online suggest that you should have a YouTube option and an Embed Code option in the screen above. You may need to run your Office installation again and check if these components are installed, or maybe your Office installation is corrupted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## **Steps to Embed a Youtube video into PowerPoint 2013:**

1. Open your Powerpoint presentation
2. Move to the slide you would like to add the video to
3. Set the Developer Tab to visible (skip this step if your Developer Tab is already visible):

   - Click File->Options
   - Click “Customize Ribbon”
   - Check mark the option “Developer” (from the Main Tabs option list on the right)
   - Click OK
4. Draw a shockwave control for the video onto your slide:

   - Click the Developer Tab
   - Click the “More Controls” (Icon looks like wrench and screwdriver under Controls)
   - Select “Shockwave Flash Object” and Click OK
   - Draw your desired rectangle video window over your slide
5. Set your video:

   - Right Click on the shockwave rectangle video
   - Select “Property Sheet”
   - Enter your Youtube url into the field “Movie:”
     e.g. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QcvjoWOwnn4
   - Edit the url by replacing `/watch?v=` with `/v/`
     e.g. http://www.youtube.com/v/QcvjoWOwnn4
   - Close the Property Sheet
6. Done!

Answer (score 3):

You can always download the video from Youtube (search the Net), convert it to a format the PC knows maybe using Windows Movie Maker) and then embed the video onto the Powerpoint.

The main advantage is that you won't need to use the Internet while presenting. In most presentations I made I found that Internet access was unreliable, at best. The disadvantage is that you need to have space to store the video.

Comment: I know I could download it, but I want to keep my presentations from exploding in size. And I'll be in a classroom with very reliable Internet, so that's not an issue.

Comment: You can also download the video, put it in the same place as your presentation, and **link** to it (_relative link_), instead of embedding it. Just ensure you carry the video along with the presentation file.

Comment: Actually, Powerpoint *prevents* from exploding in size, as it already knows video files are large, and as such, **all** embedded videos like this are relatively linked.

Comment: @Doktoro Reichard:  actually, no.  Since PPT 2010, videos are embedded by default.

Comment: @Steve I wouldn't say "by default" but rather "by design" (well, semantics are bothersome). This [Microsoft Support](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/powerpoint-help/embed-or-link-to-a-video-from-your-presentation-HA010374729.aspx) page explains all this.

Comment: @DoktoroReichard The most frustrating part is that same support page has instructions for embedding a Youtube video on PPT 2010 that no longer works in 2013.

Answer (score 2):

You need to find get the embed code from the Youtube video page and copy it. You then need to go to *Insert > Media > Video*, choose *Video from website* and paste in the embed code.

[Research/Source](http://office.microsoft.com/en-au/powerpoint-help/link-to-a-video-on-youtube-from-powerpoint-2010-HA102636549.aspx?CTT=5&origin=HA010374729)

Comment: Those instructions are for 2010. The process has changed, and the screenshot in my question shows where the From Website should be, but is not.

Comment: Oh I see, my apologies. That's strange - as you probably know, the menu you mentioned in your question is the correct place, but you should have more options available. Could you please add your version of Office (e.g. Home and Business, Professional Plus, 365, RT, etc) to the original question? Also, is the computer in question connected to the internet behind a non user/password required proxy? (e.g. a non corporate proxy or just normal ADSL)

Comment: It's already there, but it's Professional Plus, and it's just a regular old Internet connection. No proxy.

Answer (score 0):

Between problems with getting this to work reliably and YouTube changing their embedding codes (and, I suspect, potential legal issues) MS has disabled this feature.

It might work to use Shyam Pillai's free LiveWeb add-in (http://skp.mvps.org) to embed a web browser instance, then set the web browser to the you tube vid's URL.

Comment: Do you have a source for the disabling? I didn't see anything about that.

Comment: It's changed so recently that MS may not have documented it yet (if they plan to at all).

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the workaround given int the following post.

www.techhstuff.blogspot.in

Regards,
TechhNettGuru.

Comment: Would be commendable to put more information in your post rather than a link. :)

Comment: Or please at least link to the appropriate post. Nothing on the front page of the site mentioned PowerPoint.

Answer (score 0):

You can add services like Facebook for Office, Flickr, or YouTube so you can quickly add images, videos, or files to an Office file by clicking File > Account > Add a service.
If you can’t choose or see a service, you might need to sign in to Office. Or you might see different services if you are signed in under a Personal or Organization account.